# Do depressed people go to hell for having rebellious thoughts or commit suicide?

Tags: sin, suicide

What is the Islamic rule for people with mental illnesses, such as depression, anxiety or schizophrenia who commit suicide? Or someone having negative thoughts about life, other people and themselves.

Is depression or anxiety forgiven for being a mental illness? On the other hand who commits suicide with a sane mind?

Answer (score 2):

As *@Butarek Hd* responded, humans are not accountable for mental insanity. That is beyond their control.

- As far as common anxiety, depression, etc - they evidently fall under trials and tribulations of this world. As Allah (SWT) states in the Quran:

> "And We will surely test you with something **of fear** and hunger and a loss of wealth and lives and fruits, but give good tidings to the patient,
>   Who, when disaster strikes them, say, "Indeed we belong to Allah, and indeed to Him we will return." 2:155-156

- If you are diagnosed with **clinical depression** (different from regular
  depression), one should consult with their physician because that is
  a mental disorder. Not excluding the Islamic solutions to any
  illness: Dhikr (remembrance of Allah), Quran, Dua, Extra prayers,
  etc.
- Finally, **suicide is forbidden**

  > It was narrated from Thaabit ibn Dahhaak (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (blessings and peace of Allaah
  >   be upon him) said: “Whoever kills himself with something will be
  >   punished with it on the Day of Resurrection.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari
  >   (5700) and Muslim (110).

And Allah (SWT) knows best.

Answer (score 1):

according to islamqa.info , One might be crazy (insane) , or is under the ruling on those who are affected by insanity . In this case he will not be held accountable.

so whatever he is having , depression , anxiety , schizophrenia  , or any psychological or mental illness , if it affects his mind and cannot know what he is saying or doing , then  he will not be held accountable. otherwise , he will be held accountable. so there is no general ruling for such cases , according to what I understand.

and God knows best

see :

https://islamqa.info/en/111938

https://islamqa.info/en/146375

https://islamqa.info/en/14392